# javascript - why is my Fraction output swapping numerator and denominator?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I think I'm taking crazy pills. Trying to use `Fraction` from the `fraction` module to make decimals into `n`/`m` fractions. Everything works fine, but for .33 it seems to flip numerator and denominator values.

```js
//example
//count is 0.3333333333333333
const newCount = Math.round(count * 100) / 100;
console.log(`New Count is: ${newCount}`);
const [int, dec] = newCount.toString().split('.').map(el => parseInt(el, 10));

if (int === 0) {
   const fr = new Fraction(newCount);
   console.log(`fr is: ${fr}`);
   return `${fr.numerator}/${fr.denominator}`;
}
```

[image: console output]

Numerator should be 1 and denominator should be 3? am I missing something?'

both `int` and `dec` are correct in the array (didnt console log but have looked there)

Comment: 0.33 is 33/100, what exactly is the problem

Comment: `One third` and `0.33` are not equal.

Comment: What happens if you don't truncate count to 2 digits?

Comment: oh wait yeah... I'm not a maths guy, how I get it to eval to `1/3`? do i just have to hardcode it in there?

Comment: Why are you rounding it?

Comment: What does `new Fraction(1/3)` give you?

Comment: You cannot represent `1/3` as number with a finite decimal part.